# Why is there three pixels of whitespace below this table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is meant to be 146px fixed in height, however it's coming up with a row of three pixels at the bottom. As you can see from the code I've tried a few things trying to eliminate any rogue spacing/padding, but nothing seems to fix it. The only thing that resolves it is if I change the DOCTYPE from `<!doctype html>` to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`

Can anyone pinpoint why the table isn't rendering at 146 pixels (it should be snapping to the height of those two images that are in there)?

```html
<table style="width: 100%;padding: 0;margin: 0;border: 0;border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;margin: 0;border: 0;" width="50%" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
    <td style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;margin: 0;border: 0;" width="263"><img src="images/application_logo.jpg" width="263" height="146" border="0"></td>
    <td style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;margin: 0;border: 0;" width="443" bgcolor="#000000">

      <table width="443" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

        <tr>
          <td valign="middle">

            <font class="bodyfont" style="font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF">APPLICATION...</font><br>
            <font class="bodyfont" style="font-weight: bold; color: #BFDFFF">SAMPLE</font>

          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;margin: 0;border: 0;" width="274"><img src="images/application_fern.jpg" width="274" height="146" border="0"></td>
    <td style="padding: 0 0px 0 0;margin: 0;border: 0;" width="50%" background="images/application_right_bg.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Solved it - added ```img { display: block; }``` and that fixed it

Comment: Not the solution, but you seem to mixing old-style `width` attributes with modern styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your issue with the following lines of code in your CSS file.

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

You can change it to reference a class (`.`) or an ID (`#`) if you like instead of a tag reference (`img`).

---

This should fix your issue with the whitespace.